# Authy verification using parse server cloud code

Tags: android, node.js, twilio, parse-server

I want to use Authy account verification with parse server. please guide me how to use parse backend instead of express and mongodb as you demonstrated here: [ACCOUNT VERIFICATION WITH AUTHY, NODE.JS AND EXPRESS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/account-verification-node-express)

or how can I achieve the same thing in Node.js backend which have done using ruby in here: [TWILIO VERIFICATION SDK FOR ANDROID - INTEGRATION GUIDE](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/twilio-verification-sdk-integration-guide)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask questions here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Kindly provide details of how you have tried to solve the problem. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'll answer your second question, as using the [verification SDK is probably the better way for you to verify phone numbers in your Android application](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/twilio-verification-sdk-integration-guide). I assume that you have implemented the steps necessary in your Android application from [the guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/twilio-verification-sdk-integration-guide/integrating-twilio-verification-sdk-using-sample-backend).

I've translated the Ruby server you pointed to to a Node.js server using Express. You need to have installed 3 npm packages, though if you are already mounting your Parse server in Express you should have 2 of them. Anyway, this is what you need:

```
$ npm install express body-parser jsonwebtoken
```

Then a minimal server for this would be:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/verify/token', (req, res) => {
  const payload = {
    app_id: process.env.APP_ID,
    phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
    iat: Date.now()
  };

  const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.AUTHY_API_KEY, {
    algorithm: 'HS256',
    expiresIn: '1h'
  });

  res.json({ jwt_token: token });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Note: you need to export both your app id and Authy API key to the environment.